# What are some puzzle apps for android?

Tags: training, websites

I'm a big fan of lichess's tactics training, because puzzles include both winning material and checkmate sequences, and the puzzles are taken from actual games.

Unfortunately this feature isn't available on the lichess android app. Is there some other app that meets most of these requirements?

- is free
- has no limit on number of puzzles
- has both checkmate tactics and material-winning tactics
- has sufficient variety in puzzle difficulty
- has a puzzle rating / gives you a tactics rating

Any recommendations are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can look at Chess King series http://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=8196632901699712832. They are not 100% free, but available exercises fully satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lichess app for Android just added the training feature, so this question isn't relevant any more.

Answer (score 1):

Mobialia chess free have some tactical puzzles.It is mainly used for connecting to icc and fics. The tactical puzzles are taken from real games. So although, there's only a limited no of puzzles(a few hundreds), doing them over and over can help one perfect the basics.It is mainly intended for players below 2100 fide rating.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Max Chess: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dim.maxym.mychess

You can choose difficulty of puzzles and time mode. There are no puzzles limit.

Comment: Just tried it out - I assume this is your app. Well done! Is there a way to review a puzzle you've gotten wrong? I solved a few, then got one wrong and couldn't figure out how to see the correct answer or even see the position again. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Thank you, for your comment.
There is no option to view puzzles on which you made mistake. Maybe, it will be added soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and after not finding something suitable, I have set up a small, free app called the Chess Blunder Trainer.

You can find it in the Google Play Store via https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cbt.chess_blunder_trainer

You import your own games as PGN. It will identify blunder moves and generate puzzles from the position. Like this, you can replay the position and try to identify better moves. Have fun with it and let me know what you think!

[image: Chess Blunder Trainer App]

You can find out more about the app here as well: [www.chessblundertrainer.com](https://www.chessblundertrainer.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Chess Tactic Puzzles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timleg.chesstactics) is what I've been using for a while. It doesn't cost money, doesn't track your data, and doesn't serve up advertisements. As a player I think of myself as somewhere between beginner & intermediate levels, and I find some of its puzzles are easy, some difficult, and some intermediate. After trying a puzzle, you can "go back" and run through Stockfish's analysis of the position. There is also a progress tracking graph that is either a bit behind or that I don't understand (e.g. it often does something like showing my trend as downward even though I got the most recent puzzle(s) correct, or upward after missing a couple). However, for all that's involved (no cost, no unwanted instrusions), that last gripe is a minor one and I like the app.

Comment: Also: I am not the developer nor affiliated with them in any way (as far as I know).